# How to make an application that cannot open more than 1 can open more than 1 using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

If you know the Growtopia game maybe you can help me. I want to make this game can run this game more than 1 window using python. If no code is added that can make this game run more than 1 then
[this will happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IN9g.png)

```
from tkinter import *
import os
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
from subprocess import *

os.system("cls")

window = Tk()

def start_gt():
    try:
        num = int(entry.get())
        num -=1
        
        while num >= 0:
            Popen(growtopia)
            num -= 1
    except NameError:
        messagebox.showerror(title = 'Click the Browse Button',message="I Can't Find your Growtopia on your Computer. Click the Browse button First")
    except ValueError:
        messagebox.showerror(title = 'Enter numbers into the boxes',message='You can only enter Numbers')
        

def browse_gt():
    global growtopia
    growtopia = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    

window.title("Growtopia Auto 'Python' By Yudhis")
window.geometry("600x300")
window.configure(bg='#302f2f')

# ====================================== BUTTON AND FRAME

start_frame = Frame(window,
                    bg='#ff0000',
                    bd=2,
                    width=5,
                    height=5)
entry = Entry(start_frame,
            font=("Asdonuts",13),
            width=6)
start = Button(start_frame,
            text="START GT",
            command=start_gt,
            bg='black',
            fg='#ff0000',
            activebackground='black',
            activeforeground='#ff0000',
            font=('Asdonuts',15))
browse = Button(window,
                bg='black',
                fg='#ff0000',
                activebackground='black',
                activeforeground='#ff0000',
                font=('Asdonuts',12),
                text='B R O W S E',
                command=browse_gt)

# ====================================== BUTTON AND FRAME PLACE
browse.place(x=510,y=265)
start_frame.place(x=173,y=20)
Label(start_frame, text="", bg='#ff0000').grid(row=0,column=2)
start.grid(row=0,column=3)
entry.grid(row=0,column=0)


window.mainloop()
```

and that is my code. U can try it if u want. If you could help me it would be very helpful

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score -1):

you definitely need to use windows API to do that. I have done something similar 5 years ago.
If you need further help hit me up on my discord: 3zzy#5031